# In behat how to validate if I am on the right page after clicking a link

Tags: php, behat

When I click on "Laxatives"
Then I should see the '/laxatives" page

For the above behat scenario how can i validate or make sure that it redirects to correct url.
For now when i run this it redirects to correct page, but if incase it does not how will i validate through script.Kindly help

Comment: You want to validate a link? how can a link take you to an incorrect url? Please be more specific, maybe there is some misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

when there is no big amount of links you're testing, you can use `switch` statement to specify expected URL for each option. 
Otherwise I would suggest to create some class acting like translations, so when you request Laxatives, it will tell you, that "/laxatives" string must be present within the page URL. You can then specify this "translations" in some JSON or CSV file.

Then just use: `$this->assertSession()->addressMatches($regex);`  where the regex will be set by `switch` statement or loaded by the class I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest way of achieving is this:

```
Given I am on 'home-page'
When I follow 'link-to-laxatives-page'
Then I should see 'Welcome to Laxatives'
```

So `Welcome to Laxatives` is a simple text which presents in `/laxatives` page.

**Note:** If there is a text which is completely unique to the page then use that otherwise use something else.

OTHER OPTIONS:

- You can use [getCurrentUrl()](http://code-usage.com/v/Behat/Mink/Driver/BrowserKitDriver:getCurrentUrl) in your FeatureContext.
- Use already [build-in step](http://Then%20/%5Ethe%20(?i)url(?-i)%20should%20match%20(?P%3Cpattern%3E%22(?:[%5E%22]%7C%5C%5C%22)*%22)$/) which is in MinkContext